# Merge azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Basically we have 2 different Azure active directory for different organization. We need to sync first organization company directory user to another organization. How can we achieve this.

Comment: Are you talking about user migration between tenants?

Comment: @CarlZhao Actually, our website provide single sign on option for all registered company and each company has it's own active directory. so how can we do that..?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There are also no tools from Microsoft to allow you to do this.

You have couple of options here:

- Microsoft Support - open a support ticket and require user migration (not sure if/how this works)
- Consultancy company to do this for you
- Do it yourself using a lot of scripting around Microsoft Graph (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

It is relatively complex task to merge tenants. And it becomes more complex is you use any other services beside pure Identity (Azure AD) - like if you have Office 365 and mailboxes, SharePoint Online, OneDrive for Business, Power BI etc.